# Difference between camlQuery.AllowIncrementalResults=true and camlQuery.AllowIncrementalResults=false?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, caml-query, large-lists, list-view-paging

My aim is to get all items from a SharePoint List (>5000 items). I have used the standard pagination based approach and it is working fine.

```
ListItemCollectionPosition position=null;

do{
   CamlQuery caml=new CamlQuery(){ViewXml="<View><RowLimit Scope='RecursiveAll'>5000</RowLimit></View>"};
 caml.ListItemCollectionPosition = position;
   ListItemsCollection items=list.getItems(caml);
   context.Load(items);
   context.executeQuery();
   foreach(var item in items){
   //do stuff
   }
   position=items.ListItemCollectionPosition;
}while(position!=null);
```

However, I recently came across a code sample where it also includes the line:
**caml.AllowIncrementalResults=true;** in the article:
https://gp23.com.au/2019/01/16/sharepoint-online-list-view-thresholds/

I would like to know the impact for setting the AllowIncrementalResults=true.
The documentation in msdn is very sparse.

Comment: I also didn't find much information about this property except it has been added in the CSOM package released in December 2017 (v16.1.7206.1200). If that helps you narrow down the internet searches.

Comment: Yes. That's the only bit of info I got in my searches too :(.

Comment: Wow you got me trawling through the low level protocol [MS-CSOMSPT] documentation on this one.

Comment: I read that too. Did not find the answer there either. @JamesRandal